# Bind input$plotBrush and textInput together

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to bind input$plotBrush to textInput and vice versa so that when I draw my x brush on my plot it set the same boundaries ([brush]$xmin and [brush]$xmax) to the related text input and when I enter my values in my textInput, it draws me a brush on my plot whith the same boundaries entered.

I wasn't able to find any solution on accessing the [brush]$xmin and [brush]$xmax variable
(problem is : updateBrushInput does'nt exist)

Here is a reproductible example :
(the text inputs are set and returns [brush]$xmin and [brush]$xmax from the brushPlot, but the filter only works in one way)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

#Create T0New data
lat <- c(49.823, 49.823, 58.478, 57.478, 45.823)
lng <- c(-10.854,-10.854,-10.854,2.021,2.02)
date_start_min <- c(123,125,135,168,149)
T0New <- data.frame(lat,lng)

ui <- fluidPage(

  leafletOutput("map", height = "50vh"),
  textInput("input1","Date start (from 123 to 149)",value = ""),
  textInput("input2","Date end (from 123 to 149)",value = ""),
  plotOutput("distribPlot", height = "47vh",
             brush = brushOpts(id = "distribPlot_brush", direction = "x", resetOnNew = FALSE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$distribPlot_brush, {
    brush <- input$distribPlot_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      updateTextInput(session, "input1", value=brush$xmin)
      updateTextInput(session, "input2", value=brush$xmax)
    }
  })

  #filter data from plot sel
  filteredGraphData <- reactive({

    currentlyFiltered <- T0New

    if(!is.null(input$distribPlot_brush)){
      thisSel <- input$distribPlot_brush
      currentlyFiltered <- currentlyFiltered %>% 
        filter(date_start_min >= thisSel$xmin, date_start_min <= thisSel$xmax)
    }
      return(currentlyFiltered)
  })


  #Output map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenTopoMap)
  })

  observe({
      mapData <- filteredGraphData()
      mapProxy <- leafletProxy("map", session = session, data = mapData)
      mapProxy %>%
        clearGroup('A') %>%  
        addCircleMarkers(
          data = mapData,
          lat = mapData$lat,
          lng = mapData$lng,
          radius = 5,
          color = 'red',
          stroke = F,
          fillOpacity = 1,
          group = 'A'
        )
  })


  #outputPlot
  output$distribPlot <- renderPlot({

    distribPlot <- ggplot(T0New,aes(date_start_min)) +
      geom_density(col = "#053144", fill = "#43a2ca", alpha = 0.3, adjust = 0.75)

    return(distribPlot)
  })
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: seems to be an open issue? https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1456

Comment: is there any solution using javascript ?

Comment: javascript will probably be part of the solution, yes. As you can see in the issue it does not seem to be that trivial, sry.